# Communication between Firestore and ESP32

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, esp32

I am doing a project to identify people via RFID in ESP32. When performing the identification, the ESP must consult the data referring to the identified RFID TAG and display the related data on a display (name, city, date of birth).

However, I am not able to understand how I carry out this communication between ESP and Firestore. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Google can certainly help you. There are dozens to hundreds of examples of how to talk to Firestore from an ESP32. Or maybe read the documentation on one of the Firestore libraries?

Comment: Seriously? I already searched and found only this tutorial that did not serve me very well

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8ju93IYZ1A&t=716s

Answer (score 1):

The intended method of talking to the Google Cloud from an ESP32 is through the [IoT Core](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/embedded-c-getting-started). Note that this will not get you a direct connection to the Firestore - you'd have to write some cloud side code to translate MQTT messages into database queries and responses. This shouldn't be very difficult, though.

Otherwise you can send HTTPS queries directly to the [Firebase REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database). Read the Google documentation for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ESP-IDF framework for your development you can use this ESP-IDF component to communicate with Firestore (this component uses Firestore REST API via HTTPS):

- https://github.com/kaizoku-oh/firestore.git

Here is also an example using RFID and Firestore components that you can change according to your needs:

- https://github.com/kaizoku-oh/firestore-rfid-node.git